# Errors in Drupal 7 - Trying to get property of non-object in taxonomy_overview_terms()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would love to get some help here. I enabled the forums module which is part of Drupal core. When I go to add a container, I get the following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in taxonomy_overview_terms() (line 279 of   D:\Development\drupal\sites\all\modules\taxonomy\taxonomy.admin.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in taxonomy_overview_terms() (line 403 of D:\Development\drupal\sites\all\modules\taxonomy\taxonomy.admin.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in taxonomy_overview_terms() (line 405 of D:\Development\drupal\sites\all\modules\taxonomy\taxonomy.admin.inc).
```

I have tried to delete the tables and reinstall the module. I have the same module enabled on another one of our sites (which is identical in structure). But I do not get these errors on it. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I debugged a similar issue and found that the 'forum' vocabulary nav variable (forum_nav_vocabulary) was not set in my installation, and that just plain breaks things. In the forum module there are a number of calls to variable_get('forum_nav_vocabulary', ''), but unfortunately if it is not set, using an empty vid has not been properly catered for.

If you set it, make sure to use the vid and not the machine name (i.e. the number, not the name). You will need to do this with drush, via the db, or using devel module's variable editor.